# Is the sinc function related to the Gamma function?

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions, factorial, gamma-function, desmos

I was just fooling around on Desmos and entered the function $f_{n}(x)=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$. When I set $n=0$, i.e. $f_{0}(x)=\frac{1}{x!(-x)!}$, I found that the resulting function looked strikingly similar to the sinc$(\pi x)$ function. When I entered $g(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ and graphed the difference function $f(x)-g(x)$, the result was, well, zero, supposedly pointing towards the idea that $$\frac{1}{x!(-x)!} = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$ I am aware of the $\Gamma$ function but not very experienced with it. Is there a method by which we can formally arrive at this result, and is there a more general connection between $\Gamma$ and sinc? Any insights would be very much appreciated!

[image: Desmos Screenshot]

Comment: This is the well known [reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3) for the gamma function. You can use [(4.22.1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22.E1) and [(5.8.2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.8.E2) to prove it.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula is very similar to the reflection formula, which is $$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi x}$$ Taking the reciprocal and multiplying by $\pi$, we get $$\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)}=\sin (\pi x)$$

Comment: You have to divide by and not multiply by $x$. Also, your $s$ should be $x$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: Again, you have to divide by and not multiply by $x$. Or multiply by $x$ first and then take reciprocals.